# Data consolidation using Perl

Tags: perl

I have following data in a big file

```
8915, fun1, 10
8915, fun1, 8
8915, fun1, 12
8915, fun2, 5
8915, fun2, 6
8915, fun2, 4
8916, fun1, 12
8916, fun1, 13
8916, fun2, 4
8916, fun2, 5
```

I want to find the count, max, min of the functions (2nd col) elapsed time (3rd col) in each hour (first col). What will be the easiest approach in Perl? My plan is use multidimensional array,  please suggest.

```
HR      COUNT     MIN      MAX

8915     
  fun1      3       8       12
  fun2      3       4        6
8916     
  fun1      2      12       13
  fun2      2       4        5
```

Comment: The easiest approach would be to read the file into an array of arrayrefs with a CSV parser, then transform the data in the way you need to compile the report. A multidimensional array would thus be a good idea.

What have you tried? SO is not a 'post the codez for me!' site.

Comment: I am newbie in Perl.I was using following logic
`my @list = grep /\b$_[0]\b/ , <LOG>;<br/>
chomp @list;<br/>
foreach my $line (@list) {<br/>
$fun[$index]  = split(..);<br/>
$hour[$index] = split(..);<br/>
$index++;<br/>
}<br/>
my @fununiq = uniq @fun;<br/>
my @tmuniq = uniq @hour;<br/>
foreach my $line (@tmuniq) {<br/>
 my @lst = grep /\b$line\b/ , <LOG>;<br/>
chomp @lst;<br/>
foreach my $fn (@tmuniq){<br/>
if (grep /$fn/, @lst) {<br/>
 foreach my $ln (@lst){<br/>
 $val[$index] = split(..);<br/>...
      }<br/>
}}}<br/>` I know this is not straight forward and @amon logic works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a hash of hashes, where the first level key is an hour, and the second level key is a function name. The values would then be arrayrefs containing all data points. You can then extract the  min/max values. Or you could keep the current min/max values, and test against these for each new value.

To parse the input, I recommend the `Text::CSV` module.

The code would look a bit like:

```
use List::Util qw/min max/;

my %times;
while (my ($hour, $fun, $val) = ...) {
  push @{ $times{$hour}{$fun} }, $val;
}

for my $hour (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %times) {
  my $funs = $times{$hour};
  for my $fun (sort keys %$funs) {
    my $vals = $funs->{$fun};
    my $count = @$vals;
    my $min = min @$vals;
    my $max = max @$vals;
    ...;
  }
}
```